# How to hide unreacheble hosts?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I need to execute some commands through the shell module, but when I execute them on a group of hosts, they are displayed in the terminal unreachable. How to make it so that information is displayed only on available hosts?

For now, running

```bash
ansible all -m shell -a "df -h"
```

Results in:

```json
Mint-5302 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 192.168.53.2 port 22: No route to host",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Comment: `ignore_unreachable` might help in the playbook, or you need to have a callback plugin to do the magic!

Comment: it only works in playbooks

Comment: Write a playbook with the given commands and add `ignore_unreachable` as playbook vars.

Comment: I don't want in the script. I need to run a shell module from the console

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html)

Ignoring unreachable host errors

```yaml
- name: Execute shell
  shell: "df -h"
  ignore_unreachable: yes
```

And at the playbook level, to ignoring each unreachable's hosts

```yaml
- hosts: all
  ignore_unreachable: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Execute shell
    shell: "df -h"
```

Comment: The author does not want to use playbook

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behavior by using [`community.general.diy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/diy_callback.html) callback plugin.

Create `ansible.cfg` file with following content -

```ini
[defaults]
bin_ansible_callbacks = True
stdout_callback = community.general.diy

[callback_diy]
runner_on_unreachable_msg=""
```

Run your ad-hoc command and you will get the following output

```
$ ansible -m ping 192.168.10.1
PLAY [Ansible Ad-Hoc] *************************************************************************

TASK [ping] ***********************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
192.168.10.1               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```